# Extracting Text from Javascript using BeautifulSoup to obtain number of followers

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to automate the process of obtaining the number of followers for instagram for a few accounts.

For example, https://www.instagram.com/taylorswift/ etc

I have tried to use libraries like BeautifulSoup. However, one problem faced is that the number of followers is under a javascript type, and has many other text with it.

My code would be:

```html
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> url = "https://www.instagram.com/taylorswift/"
>>> page = requests.get(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
>>> script = soup.select("script")
```

May I ask how to obtain the number of followers as the only output? (i.e 76.8m) I am new to python and scripting :/ Thank you.

Comment: Well, actually, if you want to scrap a Javascript-driven web platform, you'd better stop using BeautifulSoup and start Selenium. BeautifulSoup just downloads HTML page, while Selenium is a full framework for simulating browsers. I'd recommend Selenium/PhantomJS.

Comment: @ErdinEray thank you for the suggestion, however, would there be a possible way with BeautifulSoup? I am not too sure if Instagram is a javascript driven web platform

Comment: Not by help of BeautifulSoup, but you might try to get inside of *that* script tag. Then, find what you are looking for by help of regular expressions, maybe? However, a web platform like Instagram would not hold any information in Javascript code or front-end. It is likely for Instagram to make a JSON request. If so, there is no way you can get what you want by help of BeautifulSoup.

Comment: can't you please upvote my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this code works fine for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from json import loads

username = "liamgiannini"

r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/'+username)
html = r.text.encode("utf-8")
text = html[html.index("window._sharedData = ")+21:]
text = (text[:text.index("};</script>")]+"}").replace('\\"', "")
dictionary= loads(text)
data = dictionary["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["user"]

print "followers: "+str(data["followed_by"]["count"])
```

by printing `print data.keys()` you can access a lot more information about the user